# How to trigger macro when opening Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a macro in Google Sheets that I would like run automatically when I (or my colleagues) open Google Sheets.

During my research, I have seen the function `onOpen()` that could be good but I don't know how to use it with a macro behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a simple trigger if you don't want to use **onOpen** function

Step 1 - Go to Tools >> Script Editor
Step 2 - Click on Triggers
Step 3 - Choose which function to run
Step 4 - Select event type as **"On Open"**
Step 5 - Save the trigger

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rocheux, this is absolutely what I need! I was concentrating on the onOpen function but there was more simple. Have a good day ! ;)